# Count distinct of a column based on 2 variables of another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

How to get Count distinct of a column based on 2 variables of another column in SQL?

EX:

```
EMP ID        DEPT
22            fire
21            Safety
22            Safety
26            fire
22            audit
32            actuary
44            fire
44            safety
26            safety
```

I would need the count distinct number of emp id for both fire and safety dept. Here the answer should be 3(22,26 AND 44). Could you please let me know the best way to SQL query this?

Comment: yes he can, but the only condition is that EMP ID needs to be a part of both 'fire' and 'safety' dept. Thanks!!

Comment: please  tag your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT 1 dd
FROM  tablename
WHERE dept in ('fire','safety')
GROUP BY empid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dept)  = 2
) t
```

if you want distinct list of empids :

```
SELECT empid
FROM  tablename
WHERE dept in ('fire','safety')
GROUP BY empid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dept)  = 2
```